# Removing a prefix from a Diagnostics Aggregator Group

Tags: ros, diagnostics, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to configure a diagnostics aggregator, and all of the messages have names like name_of_robot/camera, name_of_robot/laser

Is there a way to remove all of those prefixes at once?

**Edit**: Sorry for the delay. Had to find the proper bag file.

I'd like to be able to group all messages with the same prefix, i.e. all messages from one robot namespace (p1_003 here). It seems like currently you can only find-and-remove prefixes for the generic analyzer, not for an entire group.

Here is a sample laser message.

```
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 1435085520
    nsecs: 104394528
  frame_id: ''
status: 
  - 
    level: 0
    name: p1_003/laser: Hardware Status
    message: Streaming
    hardware_id: H1415783
    values: 
      - 
        key: IP Address
        value: 192.168.0.10
      - 
        key: IP Port
        value: 10940
      - 
        key: Vendor Name
        value: Hokuyo Automatic Co., Ltd.
      - 
        key: Product Name
        value: UST-10LX
      - 
        key: Firmware Version
        value: receive error.
      - 
        key: Firmware Date
        value: receive error.
      - 
        key: Protocol Version
        value: SCIP 2.2
      - 
        key: Device ID
        value: H1415783
      - 
        key: Computed Latency
        value: 0.000000000
      - 
        key: User Time Offset
        value: 0.000000000
      - 
        key: Device Status
        value: sensor is working normally
      - 
        key: Error Count
        value: 0
  - 
    level: 0
    name: p1_003/laser: Laser Scan topic status
    message: Desired frequency met
    hardware_id: H1415783
    values: 
      - 
        key: Events in window
        value: 201
      - 
        key: Events since startup
        value: 5010
      - 
        key: Duration of window (s)
        value: 5.024177
      - 
        key: Actual frequency (Hz)
        value: 40.006556
      - 
        key: Target frequency (Hz)
        value: 40.000000
      - 
        key: Minimum acceptable frequency (Hz)
        value: 38.000000
      - 
        key: Maximum acceptable frequency (Hz)
        value: 42.000000
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213072/removing-a-prefix-from-a-diagnostics-aggregator-group/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to remove these prefixes from the input to the aggregator, or its output?

If they're not present on the input, but they are showing up on the output, you may want to look at your aggregator config to see if there's a top-level AggregatorGroup that's set to your robot name.

If you can post a sample message from the `/diagnostics` topic and your aggregator config, that would help.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1